# Including my class in a Laravel 5 Project

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, laravel-5

I made a class in php with some helper methods that parse HTML files.

I'd like to use this class in my Laravel project, but I'm new to Laravel and it's not clear how to add a simple class to a Laravel 5 project.

Is this possible?  Or do I need to go to all the trouble of creating a composer package for my class, hosting it somewhere, and then `require` it in my `composer.json` file. That seems like a lot of work for including a simple PHP class, and I'm hoping there's an easier way.

Comment: Recommended reading as a starting point: http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/structure

Comment: First try some google searches, there are several ways to do that.

Comment: I did, but can't find for the new laravel. Most are for the old one

Comment: Put the class in a file, put that file somewhere, then load it using composer.  If it is a file that you want to reuse with other projects then the logical place is the vendors directory (i.e. do not tightly couple it to the current project).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As it stands right now there's not a great/easy way to do this in Laravel 5 (possibly by design).  The two approaches you can take are

### Create a new class in the `App` namespace

By default Laravel 5.0 looks for `App\` prefixed classes in the `app/` folder, so something like this should work

```
#File: app/Helpers/Myclass.php
<?php
namespace App\Helpers;
class Myclass
{
}
```

and then create your class with

```
$object = new App\Helpers\Myclass;
```

This approach, however, relies on you creating classes in the `App\` namespace, and there's some ambiguity around if the `App\` namespace is owned by Laravel, or is owned by the developer of the application.

## Create your own Namespace and Register as `PSR-4` autoloader

A better, but more complicated, approach would be to create classes in your own namespace, and then tell Laravel about this namespace by registering a new PSR autoloader.

First, you'd create the class definition

```
#File: application-lib/Myclass.php
<?php
namespace Pulsestorm;
class Myclass
{
}
```

Notice we've created a new folder off the root folder to hold our classes named `application-lib`.  You could name this folder anything you like, because in the next step, you're going to add a section to your `composer.json` file's autoloader section

```
#File: composer.json
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/",
        "Pulsestorm\\": "application-lib/"          
    }
},
```

The section we've added is this

```
"Pulsestorm\\": "application-lib/"
```

The key to the object (`Pulsestorm\`) is your namespace.  The value (`application-lib`) is the folder where composer should look for class definition files with the specified namespace.

Once you've added this to `composer.json`, you'll need to tell Composer to regenerate it's autoload cache files with the `dumpautoload` command

```
$ composer dumpautoload
Generating autoload files
```

After doing the above, you should be able to instantiate your class with

```
$object = new Pulsestorm\Myclass;
```

The "real" right way to do this would be to create a generic composer package for your helper class, and then `require` that composer package into your laravel project.  That may, however, be more work than you care to take on for a simple library helper.

Comment: @GeorgeIrimiciuc The "laravel" way doesn't make room for arbitrary classes unless they're composer managed libraries.

Answer (score 1):

If your class is generic enough to use it in other projects, the best way is to release it as a package.

Here's how you create packages with Laravel 5: http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/packages